# Invert Brown Paper Texture

Tags: adobe-photoshop, images

I am following [a tutorial](http://blog.spoongraphics.co.uk/tutorials/how-to-create-a-retro-apple-wallpaper-in-photoshop) in which one of the steps is to change the brown texture paper

[image]

to this white texture paper. The tutorial says to 'invert', but I can't understand how to do this and why it would work.

[image]

Comment: "Paste the texture over the logo, inverse the colours and adjust the Levels to give a high contrast." So it's not just invert colours, you're missing the levels step.

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial is wrong. Inverting the texture will just make it blue:

[image: Inverted texture]

Instead of inverting the colors you actually want to remove all color. Desaturate the texture by going to **Image → Adjustments → Desaturate**:

[image: Desaturated texture]

Then apply the level adjustments as the tutorial says:

[image: Finished texture]